# Попытка использовать декоратор наследуемого класса. RuntimeError: super(): no arguments

Tags: python, ооп

Есть класс `VkBot`, который содержит декоратор `handler`.

При наследовании из этого класса необходимо получить доступ к этому декоратору.

Но проблема в том, что декоратор используется до инициализации, поэтому я не могу использовать `super()` в `__init__`

Ниже привожу частичный код

```
class VkBot:
  def handler(self, command: str):
      def wrapper(func):
          return func

class MyBot(VkBot):
  _handler = super().handler

  @_handler("!setclass")
  def setclass(self):
    pass
```

Напрашивается засунуть `handler` в класс `MyBot`, но проблема в том, что с точки зрения ООП декоратор `handler` не разделимо связан с `VkBot`

Полный код я залил в [архив](https://dropmefiles.com/Z4SPx).

Пожалуйста, подскажите решение этой проблемы

Comment: ссылка битая на архив

Comment: @eri, обновил ссылку

Comment: попробовали решение `self.setclass = self.handler("!setclass")(self.setclass)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Декораторы методов проставляются до инициализации - поэтому обычный метод там работать не будет даже внутри одного класса без наследования.

Будет работать с staticmethod

```
class VkBot:
  @staticmethod
  def handler(command: str):
      def wrapper(func):
          return func
      return wrapper

class MyBot(VkBot):
  @VkBot.handler("!setclass")
  def setclass(self):
    pass
```

Для Вашего примера больше подойдет карирование и патчинг в инит

```
class VkBot:
  def handler(self, command: str):
      def wrapper(func):
          return func
      return wrapper

class MyBot(VkBot):

  def __init__(self):
    self.setclass = self.handler("!setclass")(self.setclass)

  def setclass(self):
    pass
```